# Why does my program crash after I add Listview? Android

Tags: android, listview

I am attempting to connect a listview lv to its id using

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ImTrackingListView);
```

However whenever it hits this step my program crashes and sends it to the Source not found page. 
Here is my code

```
public class ImTracking extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imtrackinglayout);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imtrackinglistview);
```

I checked to make sure that there wasn't another id with the same name. Hopefully someone can help me find out why this is happening.

edit here is the xml (I changed the id to lowercase)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <ListView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imtrackinglistview"></ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my logcat response

```
08-09 20:19:12.335: WARN/System.err(640): java.lang.ClassCastException:     android.widget.TextView
 08-09 20:19:12.354: WARN/System.err(640):     at   com.cellphone.ImTracking.onCreate(ImTracking.java:30)
 08-09 20:19:12.366: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 08-09 20:19:12.366: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
 08-09 20:19:12.374: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
 08-09 20:19:12.374: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 08-09 20:19:12.374: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
 08-09 20:19:12.384: WARN/System.err(640):     at      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-09 20:19:12.384: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 08-09 20:19:12.394: WARN/System.err(640):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
 08-09 20:19:12.394: WARN/System.err(640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-09 20:19:12.394: WARN/System.err(640):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-09 20:19:12.404: WARN/System.err(640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 08-09 20:19:12.404: WARN/System.err(640):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 08-09 20:19:12.404: WARN/System.err(640):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-09 20:19:16.847: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
 08-09 20:19:16.987: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{408bf110 com.cellphone/.ImTracking}
```

Comment: Paste the logcat trace also post the xml where your listview is. And try using lower cases for the ids

Comment: Yes post the exception and the xml where your layout is defined.

Comment: Also, depending on what is shown in the logcat, you may have not added the Activity to the AndroidManifest?

Comment: It might be helpful if you put your whole activity and all xml up on pastebin or something similar so nothing is missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project, for some reason the error contains a `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class cast exception in ImTracking  file , post the error from log cat.Select E - and the last exception thrown would be in red , paste that.